# Access another module's entity

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am using two module in my zend project. One is administration and another is client. I have created one entity in administration module. Now, I want to access that file. Should I need to copy that file into Client module's Entity? OR I can access it by giving it's path. If is that so, then what will be the path?

Answer (score 1):

Going from a Software-Design-Perspective, you should not need the Entity itself, but rather you should create a **Service** that let's other Modules access the DB / Entities.

Other than that tho, just `use OtherModule\Entity\NewsEntity;` and... `new NewsEntity();`. This is basic PHP 5 Namespace stuff. See [Namespaces in under 120 Seconds](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d1kDT8YFAhI).

Answer (score 0):

No you can just access using their namespace:

```
$myEntity = new \EntityModule\EntityName\EntityFolder\Entity();
```